# How to do I set the default value for a member of the type BOOLEAN_FIELD in a derived class from foundry.abstract.DocumentData in foundry vvt?

Tags: javascript, game-engine

Is there a hook / overwriteable function, when a placeable foundry vvt object was succesfully added to the scene and is ready to be used?

calling

```
const myown_data = { give_me_icecream: true }
canvas.scene.updateEmbeddedDocuments('ContainerName',[{ _id: this.data._id, ...myown_data }])
```

in

```
 _onCreate
```

complains that the data could not be written / saved when I create the object. But when I reload the scene the data is written to all objects of the type without a problem. I would like to just to set some default values for a BOOLEAN_FIELD or any other DocumentField in a foundry.abstract.DocumentData Class, which should be used only when the object is created for the first time.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to overwrite the   _initialize () function of DocumentData (in the module folder it is name something like ModuleNameData.js).

```
export class MyOwnClassData extends foundry.abstract.DocumentData {
  static defineSchema () 
{ 
      _id: fields.DOCUMENT_ID,
      scene: {
        ...fields.DOCUMENT_ID,
        required: false,
        nullable: true
      },
      my_own_member: fields.BOOLEAN_FIELD
}
  _initialize () {
    super._initialize()
    this.my_own_member = true
  } 
}
```